# why is this filter not working properly?

Tags: angularjs

I have a filter with a very weird behavior.

this way works only with the 1 array, is not search thru `leagues.name`

```
<input type="text"
       ng-model="query">

<div ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter = (sports | filter:query)">
   <strong>
     {{sport.name}}
   </strong>
   <div ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues | filter:query"
        on-tap="goToLines(league)">
        {{league.name}}
   </div>
</div>
```

it doesn't matter if I remove `|filter:query` from the second `ng-repeat`

this way works only with the second array: `leagues.name`

```
<div ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter = (sports | filter:query)">
     <strong>
       {{sport.name}}
     </strong>

    <input type="text"
           ng-model="query">

      <div ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues | filter:query">
        {{league.name}}
      </div>
</div>
```

so, my question is, why do I have to change the position of the input in order to have it working ?

and what can I do in order to have it working with both arrays ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. Just notice you are using the same `query` param to filter both `sports` and `sport.leagues`. Here's [my working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/FWOezbHRCXjnnA6qCMN5) (filter by the word "soccer" to get results from both):

### js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.sports = [{name: 'soccer', leagues: [{name: 'american league'}, {name: 'english league'}, {name: 'world soccer league'}]}]
});
```

### html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="query">
  <div ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter = (sports | filter:query)">
    <strong>
      {{sport.name}}
    </strong>
    <div ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues | filter:query" on-tap="goToLines(league)">
      {{league.name}}
     </div>
  </div>    
</body>
```

Comment: you did a js fiddle ?

Comment: and how is that about the same query ? can you explain that please. i am new to filters. is weird but in my app is not working

Comment: Your filter by `query` in both repeaters. It's the same model in both places. When you type in the input box it filters the sports and the leagues by the same word.

Can you link a plunkr of your code?

Comment: [I have this Plknr which works correctly](http://plnkr.co/edit/FJ45nV6gdwp3SkRglPeW?p=preview) but not in my app, I do not know why